# (flask)-sqlalchemy query, have to import all models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy where for any query I would need to import all the related models.

Now my auth.views.py looks like this (first few lines of programming this thing so just a test view)

```
from flask import jsonify                                                   

from . import auth                                                          
from app.models.user import User                                            


@auth.route('/', methods=['GET'])                                            
def index():                                                                 
    users = User.query.all()                                                     
    return jsonify({'name': users[0].name})
```

Now I'm getting an error

"InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|User|user, expression 'Course' failed to locate a name ("name 'Course' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the  class after both dependent classes have been defined."

I have a project where i have a models package like so

```
app                                                                         
├── auth                                                                    
│   ├── __init__.py                                                         
│   └── views.py                                                            
├── __init__.py                                                             
└── models                                                                  
    ├── assignment.py                                                       
    ├── base.py                                                             
    ├── client.py                                                           
    ├── course.py                                                           
    ├── __init__.py                                                         
    ├── submission.py                                                       
    └── user.py
```

my user class has a many to many with Course and a one to many with Submission.

This is solved by importing the Course (and then Submission, and then the relations from there, eventually all the models basically.)

At work for Pyramid projects we also work with SQLAlchemy but I never have to import all the models to do my work. Any ideas whats up? I really can't figure this out and I haven't been able to google it.

User looks like this

```
user_course = db.Table(                                                     
    'user_course', db.Model.metadata,                                          
    db.Column('student_id', UUID, db.ForeignKey('user.id'),                    
              primary_key=True),                                               
    db.Column('course_id', UUID, db.ForeignKey('course.id'),                   
              primary_key=True)                                                
)                                                                              


class User(db.Model):                                                          
    id = db.Column(UUID, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), primary_key=True) 
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)                      
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)                       
    insertion = db.Column(db.String(15))  # tussenvoegsel                      
    # email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)                
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)                       

    enrolled_courses = db.relationship('Course', secondary=user_course,        
                                       backref='students')                     
    managed_courses = db.relationship('Course', backref='teacher')             

    submissions = db.relationship('Submission', backref='student')             

    @property                                                                  
    def name(self):                                                            
        return "{}{}{}".format(                                                
            self.firstname + " ",                                              
            self.insertion + " " if self.insertion else "",                    
            self.lastname                                                      
        )                                                                      

    @property                                                                  
    def password(self):                                                        
        raise AttributeError("Password is not a readable attribute")           

    @password.setter                                                           
    def password(self, password):                                              
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt(12))       

    def verify_password(self, password):                                       
        return bcrypt.hashpw(password, self.password_hash) == \                
            self.password_hash
```

Comment: If you never import your `models.course` module, the code never executes and your Course class is never actually created and registered with `sys.modules`.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to importing all the modules before hand. That would suck to do manually everytime you introduce something new. I also assumed that wehn connecting to the db the metadata would load all the tables. But thanks for the pointer. I will give my own solution in an answer,

Comment: My advice would be to put your models import one module, rather than splitting them up like that. ["Flat is better than nested."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: That's fine when the models are small but when they get bigger and receive more methods it's more readable to have them seperate. At least that's my personal feeling about this, could be a wrong feeling :))

Comment: @MohammedKareem you are spot on (7 years later). As apps grow you can't have all your classes in one file, nor all your models in a `/models` directory. SQLAlchemy needs to evolve with the times to support complex file structures for modern apps.

Comment: Are the Alembic docs completely silent on this? I'd be surprised if this wasn't mentioned somewhere in either the Alembic or the SQLAlchemy docs. Having said that, this is not special to Alembic or SQLAlchemy. It's true anywhere we would want to "find" all the child classes of a parent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to stick to the one-file-per-class scheme, in my opionion, the cleaner option would be to do the imports in the model package's init:

`models/__init__.py:`

```
from user import User
from client import Client
from course import Course
# plus your remaining classes
```

Then you can import the classes as

```
from models import User
```

which makes things more readable and would allow to mix the one-file-per-class scheme with modules containing multiple classes, while still being able to import all classes in a "flat" manner from `models`.

Comment: I had a solution that did it dynamically, but you're absolutely right about readability. So I ended up going with your solution.

Comment: This worked for me. If you are still facing any issue, look at the error message carefully, it shows what is missing. It might be the case that some file is out of module (for example plain tables that you created for many-many relationship), if so, import those files too in __init__.py

Answer (score 7):

Ok so apparantly you can't get around loading all the modules. I didn't want to do this manually so I resorted to this in `__init__.py`. Now all the modules will be executed like the comment said needed to happen.

```
import inspect                                                              
import pkgutil                                                                 
import importlib                                                               
import sys                                                                     


def import_models():                                                           
    thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]                                         

    for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(                   
            thismodule.__path__, thismodule.__name__ + '.'):                   
        module = importlib.import_module(module_name, loader.path)             
        for name, _object in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass):      
            globals()[name] = _object                                                                                     

import_models()
```