# Creating models in multiple models.py for a flask blueprint app at startup

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm unsure of how/when the models.py files get picked up by flask on start up for a multiple module app. I would like the app to create missing tables on start up but it doesn't seem to do that here.

The repo is here
https://github.com/CodeHostedHere/channel_response_bot

The models file that isn't being seen is here
https://github.com/CodeHostedHere/channel_response_bot/blob/master/slash_commands/models.py

Database is created here, imported to extensions and imported around the app
https://github.com/CodeHostedHere/channel_response_bot/blob/master/database.py

Comment: Just as a comment bout your Repo, include a `.gitignore` file with which you remove `venv` and `__pycache__`.

Comment: You need to import all the models: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217076/flask-sqlalchemy-query-have-to-import-all-models. You are not importing your "Rule" class anywhere. However, your repo structure looks very chaotic, perhaps take a look at Miguel Grinbergs tutorial: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I took 20 minutes to restructure things to match [this Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications) and it all works now. The DB is created at the top most `__init__.py` and then imported around the app. This was made possible by

```
# Define the application directory
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Previously this hadn't worked for me. I actually needed to have the file I run to start flask, in a directory that doesn't have its own `__init__.py`. I believe missing this parent directory was why my initial attempts failed.

Truth be told, this tutorial is actually also missing the line to commit to the database:

`db.session.commit()` directly after `db.create_all()`

I can now structure my flask app in to separate logical components and share the db connection across them. I had avoided the Ginsberg tutorial previously because it is just a single models.py